# Cronjob sends out mail but I did not specify one...?

Tags: cron

Have built an asterisk system using Ubuntu everything works great however I have one question.

Have created a cron job and I receive an email which I did not specify in the `crontab -e` now the job runs, but send out an email which I can't figure out how it is being sent.

Here is what I get in my gmail account

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: AST.ORG

root@ast.org
#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##

Original message headers:

Received: from mail-ob0-f176.google.com (209.85.214.176) by mail2.ast.org
 (192.168.10.11) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 8.3.327.1; Sat, 31 Aug 2013
 01:05:35 -0600
Received: by mail-ob0-f176.google.com with SMTP id uz19so2697286obc.7
        for <root@ast.org>; Sat, 31 Aug 2013 00:05:32 -0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: Are you asking why cron sends you a mail, or [how to stop cron from doing so](http://askubuntu.com/q/175464/169736)?

Answer (score 2):

By default, Cron will send out notifications to @ (so if you log on as jim and your system is called mypc.local, cron will send notifications to jim@mypc.local by default). You can change this email address by adding the following line to the top of your crontab file (by running crontab -e).

```
MAILTO="myemail@gmail.com"
```

This is a per user change, so if you have multiple users on your system, you will need to do this for each of them.